# Google Maps app force closes - Android Studio

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-fragments

I know this question has been asked time and time again, but it hasn't been answered and I have searched for hours trying to figure this out but the app I am working on integrates google maps. It utilizes the Side Navigation Drawer that slides out and you can select fragments that then switch the view. That being said I have all libraries necessary installed for this app to function, it compiles and builds correctly but whenever I click on the fragment that houses the app, it crashes. So here are my files.

MainActivity.java -

```
package com.raziel.android.publictoilet;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
    implements NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks {

/**
 * Fragment managing the behaviors, interactions and presentation of the navigation drawer.
 */
private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;

/**
 * Used to store the last screen title. For use in {@link #restoreActionBar()}.
 */
private CharSequence mTitle;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
    mTitle = getTitle();

    // Set up the drawer.
    mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(
            R.id.navigation_drawer,
            (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));

}


@Override
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {

     //Switches the Fragmentx.java

    Fragment fragment;
    switch (position){
        case 1:
            fragment = FirstFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = SecondFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
            break;
        case 3:
            fragment = ThirdFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
            break;

    }

    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1))
            .commit();
}

public void onSectionAttached(int number) {
    switch (number) {
        case 1:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section1);

            break;
        case 2:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section2);
            break;
        case 3:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section3);
            break;
        case 4:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section4);
            break;
    }
}





public void restoreActionBar() {
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setTitle(mTitle);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    if (!mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen()) {
        // Only show items in the action bar relevant to this screen
        // if the drawer is not showing. Otherwise, let the drawer
        // decide what to show in the action bar.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        restoreActionBar();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    /**
     * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
     * number.
     */
    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }


   //Switches views and inflates fragments in container

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = null;
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        switch(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)) {
            case 1:
                rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
                break;
            case 2:
                rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.map, container, false);
                break;
            case 3:
                rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.submittoilet, container, false);
                break;
            case 4:
                //rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_info, container, false);
                break;
        }
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        ((MainActivity) activity).onSectionAttached(
                getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER));
       }
   }

}
```

map.java - This is holds the acutal "map code" that's because with the side layout under the MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity...NavigationDrawerCallbacks it cannot implement two different callback functions. 
    package com.raziel.android.publictoilet;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class map extends Activity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

// Used to call the map and inflate fragment in container
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.map);

    MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.the_map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-33.867, 151.206);

    map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(sydney, 13));

    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .title("Sydney")
            .snippet("The most populous city in Australia.")
            .position(sydney));
     }
}
```

Now there are  sections on the side. All with labels and such the one that holds the map is named map.xml -

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            tools:context=".MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment">



<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
           android:id="@+id/the_map"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my AndroidManifest.xml file. This contains all the necessary parts that might be needed for my map app such as my API_KEY which is included.

AndroidManifest.xml -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.raziel.android.publictoilet"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

<!-- Include required permissions for Google Mobile Ads to run -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<android:uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    android:maxSdkVersion="18" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.raziel.android.publictoilet.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.raziel.android.publictoilet.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyAD8T-3hzTjWAJEuM4jQoUd-wj7IC6k2sc" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.raziel.android.publictoilet.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <!-- Include the AdActivity and InAppPurchaseActivity configChanges and themes. -->
    <activity
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.purchase.InAppPurchaseActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.IAPTheme" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.wallet.api.enabled"
        android:value="true" />

    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.wallet.EnableWalletOptimizationReceiver"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wallet.ENABLE_WALLET_OPTIMIZATION" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

The logcat shows that it is caused by:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: API key not found.  Check that <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="your API key"/> is in the <application> element of AndroidManifest.xml
```

But the thing is I cannot change the AndroidManifest.xml file to fix this issue because it auto-regenerates every build! And as you can clearly see it is in the AndroidManifest.xml. I have tried making it read-only but then it just compiles forever not throwing any errors. Can anyone please help. Again this is in Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind I fixed it. The app was generating a AndroidManifest.xml file and I was trying to edit that. That was the wrong one. The correct one is located in app/src/main and I added my key to that. Thanks to the guy that down voted me, real helpful.